# Positive-Definite Matrix Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

I want to prove that the matrix is positive definite using the fact that:

> If $A$ is symmetric and $\langle x, Ax \rangle$ > $0$ for a nonzero vector $x$ then $A$ is positive.
>
> So I have the matrix : $A$ =$\begin{bmatrix} 10&-3&0\\-3&10&0\\0&0&9\end{bmatrix}$.
>   And I already checked that $A$ is symmetric, as $A=A^T$
>
> and then I also compute that
>
> $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 10a^2+10b^2+9c^2 -6ab$,  so is it that true that eventhough I have one negative number (-6ab), $\langle x,Ax \rangle$ is still positive ?

Comment: have you had multivariable calculus ?

Comment: No. I am not sure what is that?

Comment: Derivatives of functions with multiple variables are a part of that course. It gives a general tool to show positive definiteness of such things. However, @ComFreek gave you a more elementary answer, which requires to be able to fiddle with numbers. (But it's more elegant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having negative terms in the resulting polynomial does not necessarily mean that the overall polynomial function attains values $\leq 0$. Indeed, we can prove it to be strictly positive for every nonzero vector $x = (a,b,c)^T$.

So in your last step you reached

$$\langle x, Ax \rangle = 10a^2 + 10b^2 + 9c^2 - 6ab$$

Do you notice this suspicious mixed term $-6ab$? That should ring a bell! It commonly occurs in the identity $(u-v)^2 = u^2 - 2uv + v^2$.
Let's see if we can manipulate it to reach the LHS of the identity:

$$
\begin{align*}
 &10a^2 + 10b^2 + 9c^2 - 6ab\\
 =& ??? + ??? + 9c^2 + 3(a^2-2ab+b^2)\\
 =& 7a^2 + 7b^2 + 9c^2 + 3(a^2-2ab+b^2)\\
 =& 7a^2 + 7b^2 + 9c^2 + 3(a-b)^2
\end{align*}
$$
Usually, I would do the step with $???$, but I explicitly listed it for you here. In this step you just attempt to write $-6ab$ in the form of the identity I mentioned and *then* try to adjust the other summands, so that we indeed have a valid equality from the previous line.

Can you now prove how the expression on the last line is always $> 0$ for every $x = (a, b, c)^T \neq 0$?

By the way, I think in general going the eigenvalue way, i.e. a symmetric matrix is positive definite iff. all eigenvalues are $> 0$, is more systematic and easier.

Comment: but in you still have a negative term, namely 3(a-b)^2

Comment: Not anymore, you have the sum of three squares. the square of a number is always positive ^^

Comment: Take a look at 3*(3-10)^2. Compute it, and you'll find 3*49 > 0 I mean, go ahead, plug in some numbers, and convince yourselt. Alternatively, Take a look at the graph of x^2 and you'll see that no matter the x, it's positive. Replace that x with a-b and you see that it is always positive.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kai Note though, that if we had reached the expression $a^2 + b^2$, then the matrix would *not* be positive definite since for $x = (0, 0, 10)^T$ we have that $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$. But here, if $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$, we can conclude that every summand of our expression is $0$, which implies $a = b = c = 0$.